# Should I do additional cardio?

Tags: diet, bodybuilding, cardio, gym

If I ride my bike to the gym, which is a mile from my house, and back home, should I do cardio at my gym? I am also lifting weights 4 times a week alternating between chest, delts, triceps and then back, biceps, legs, and I run for 15 minutes after my 30-90 minute weight training. My goal is to gain muscle and become more fit at the same time. I am 6'2, 26 years old, 175 lbs, and 7% body fat percentage. I am bulking and eating enough, I think; should I run or is my commute enough?

Comment: Enough for what?  You make no mention of your goals.

Comment: Goal is to gain muscle and become more fit at the same time

Comment: One mile bicycle ride is what... 5 minutes?

Comment: Maybe give or take a minute

Comment: What is your height, age, weight and body fat percentage? If you are fat but strong the answer will be different than if you are skinny and relatively weak.

Comment: 6'2, 26, 175, 7%

Comment: 6'2" tall, 175 lbs with 7% body fat and you're attempting to bulk up? If you're 175 lbs with 7% body fat, I think you should be extremely muscular by now. Or is there something wrong with the numbers?

Comment: @Kneel Before Zod: What's wrong with trying to bulk up even more?

Comment: @RobSterach Nothing.....I'm actually referring to your current numbers. I'm unable to determine the validity of those numbers. According to your question, you want to be more fit *(i.e. less fat, more muscles).* At 7%, 175 lbs, you're already shredded. I'd like someone more experienced in bodybuilding to determine how good these numbers are. BTW, [here's an image of the body fat percentages](http://healthiack.com/images/body-fat-percentage-chart-men-women.jpg)

Comment: Although aimed at beginners, [this CDC page](http://www.cdc.gov/physicalactivity/basics/adults/index.htm) says that 10 minutes at a time is the minimum needed for benefits, and you are getting that with your running.  It also says, however, that you need a total of 2 1/2 hours per week (less depending on intensity), and you may be below that.  If you can make specific for yourself what cardio goals you need to achieve in order to consider yourself having become more fit, then you can decide whether or not you need to further tailor your routine.

Comment: I may have lied... I sincerely apologize. Check out my new question and you'll see what I mean. http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/26162/need-help-dropping-body-fat-to-8-12

Answer (score 5):

> If I ride my bike to the gym, which is a mile from my house, and back
>   home, should I do cardio at my gym.

A 1 mile bike ride really doesn't qualify as a "cardio workout".

> I am also lifting weights 4 times a week ... and I run for 15 minutes
>   after my ... weight training

I really don't think this is enough workout that you need to worry about either.

Anecdotally, I would think "cardio" starts interfering with your strength training if you're pushing north of five hours a week or ~45 minutes a day. I walk about two hours a day, and I would never consider that "cardio"; it's just going for a walk.

There's a lot of room between sedentary couch sitting and cardio training that can reduce muscle hypertrophy. Being an active person (riding a bike to work, running a few minutes, walking for a few hours every day) is completely healthy and should't be viewed as a detriment.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the first answer, it depends.  Cardio has two main uses:

1) It increases the amount of work you can do in a given workout session.  As you get further into a workout, the aerobic system provides more and more of the energy used to lift the weights.  Stronger aerobic system = more reps/sets completed.
2) It increases the calories your body needs for that day, and increases your metabolism for a number of hours afterwards (provided the cardio lasts long enough and is intense enough).

So, with these two in mind, I would say do more cardio if:

-You want to be able to handle more volume in your weight workouts, and/or

-You want your body to burn more calories

Also, as a side note, biking 1 mile to the gym is basically negligible.  15 minutes of running is also not sufficient duration to be considered unless the intensity is very high.  Consider at least 30 minutes of cardio for low intensity.  If you want to do high-intensity cardio, you can spend less time, however it also usually involves higher risk of injury.

Comment: Hmmm, "do more cardio if you want to be able to handle more volume in your weight workouts". "Stronger aerobic system = more reps/sets completed" - if you are doing insane amounts of reps maybe, else I doubt it.

Comment: I'd like to refer you to this article.  http://www.strengtheory.com/avoiding-cardio-could-be-holding-you-back/
If you are lifting using a large muscle group (like legs) with any significant amount of weight, your aerobic system comes into play in a big way.  Where do you think the energy to keep you going comes from?

Answer (score -3):

The answer is simple:

1) If your goal is to lose weight - yes, do cardio!

2) If your priority is to put on mass and muscle, dont do it.

It all depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I'd say there's definitely a false dichotomy here. It's not as black-and-white as only two options.

Comment: Agree with both people above.  It DOES depend on what you are trying to achieve but it isn't as simple as that.

Comment: Higher muscle ratios will help lose weight, as muscle burns more energy than fat. Cardio != burning fat as an absolute rule.