# Need help dropping body fat to 8-12%?

Tags: weightlifting, cardio, body-fat, abdominals

So I am a 16 yr old young male nearing 17, about 160 Ibs, about 6'0, and in the 13-15% body fat range. I'd like to get down to 8-12% instead. Currently, I train my chest, traps, triceps, and legs together 2-3 times a week along with my lats, biceps, and shoulders together 2-3 times a week. Each weightlifting session tolls to about 45 minutes. I don't have a designated cardio workout, but I frequently walk, bike, and swim quite often. I average 8 hours of sleep a night. I believe I have a mesomorphic body type. I eat healthy and only treat myself every 7-15 days. I eat about 2500 calories a day, 100 g of protein a day, 30 g fiber, 50-60 g healthy fat(oils, nuts, etc.), and I avoid those sugary and artificial foods. My arms, shoulders, back, and chest are all defined, it is my abs and legs that are the problem. May I ask for advice?

Comment: Have you tried playing with your macros? Right now, 16% of your daily intake is protein and 18%-22% is fat. That means 62%-66% of your intake is from carbs (that's relatively high). I'd personally bump up your protein by 5%-10% of your daily intake. I'd also raise your fat by around 5%. But you need to play around with them and see what works for you (sustainability, performance, etc).

Comment: @AlexL How did you obtain the 16% protein and 22% fat from 100g protein, 30g fiber, and 60g fat?

Comment: Carbs and protein provide *roughly* 4 kcal/g and fats provide *roughly* 9 kcal/g. So he's eating about 400 kcal and 540 kcal of protein and fats respectively. This works out to be about 16% and 22%. The amount of fiber consumed didn't affect my arithmetic, since it's a good amount, depending on how regular his bowel movements are (which is only mildly relevant).

Comment: @Kneel-Before-ZOD - Also, fiber is generally considered to be the undigestable (and thus calorically insignificant) parts of foods. Its recommend for better motility and excretion, as well as binding in the colon.

Comment: Get a training coach who knows how to get sub-10% body fat.  It's possible, but the advice is going to be specific to you and your situation.  A good coach will help you make the right decisions to get there.  You are already in a healthy body fat range, which is as good as online advice can take you.

Answer (score 2):

**Eat.**

The reason why you're having such a hard time getting rid of that last bit of fat is that **you have almost no muscle** for your body to maintain. Given your stats, eating under maintenance is that last thing you need to do.

My advice would be to eat above maintenance (which I'd guess in your case is around 2700-2800 kcal), adding about 500 kcal to your macros (so 3200-3300 kcal), though that may be too conservative. I would up your protein and fat intake by 50% and 100% (so 150g and 100-120g, respectively) and fill the rest of your daily calories with carbs. Keep lifting just like you're doing now, making sure to challenge yourself.

Do this until you've gained 10-15 pounds. Then you can start worrying about losing that bit of fat (which will be very easy to do, given your much increased muscle mass). Sadly, there are no shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to reduce fat and maintain/increase muscle, eat a bit less in general and add more protein if possible, 100 g isn't bad, but could be better.

Your training, sleeping and eating habits seem very good so it should just be a matter of cutting a few (like 500) kcal/day to get lean.